# Trim a dajango model attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a project in django, witch uses database first. The problem is the data format, because they have a lot of blank space. As I am using rest_framework, I would like to trim the objects before pass it to the serializer, because if I try to do something like
nombre = serializers.CharField(source='nombre.strip')
it says that I cannot use build-in functions. So, if anyone can help me I it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

you need SerializerMethodField.

More here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

In your case:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # any staff here
    nombre = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # other staff here
    
    def get_nombre(self, obj):
        return f'{obj.nombre}'.strip()
```

Comment: right way to do it.